# R: go through a sequence of numbers and choose the highest one

Tags: r, string, seq

I am scrapping data from a website, and in this context, data tidying gets kind of hard.

what I have right now is a string of numbers that go into a sequence, let's say

```
    a<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
```

The first value that I'm looking for is 3, the second one is 5, and the third one will be 4. 
So basically, I want to go through the sequence 1:5 and choose the highest value, to have the final output as

```
    a<-c(3,4,5)
```

I thought about choosing the maximum values, such as

```
    a<-sort(a, decreasing = T)
    a<-a[1:3]
```

But this won't count, cause the final product is:

```
    [1] 5 4 4
```

where the small values are discriminated. Any ideas if this could be possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. What's the rule for selecting numbers? Does order matter? Maybe more examples would help?

Comment: In case you want to group "a" by occurences of "1", you could use `tapply(a, cumsum(a == 1), max)`

Comment: An alternative that assumes each new sequence starts with 1, `a[which(c(a, 1) == 1) - 1L]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort(unlist(lapply(split(a, cumsum(c(1, diff(a)) != 1)), max), use.names = FALSE))
#[1] 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is the right answer; does exactly what I need. @d.b May I ask you how did you come to it? I would like to understand so maybe I can use it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

not entirely sure if this is what you're asking for. i think what you're wanting is to see which of your values you have in your vector.

try this:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
search_values = 3:5

# unique values
search_values = a[a %in% search_values]
unique(search_values)

# counts of values
table(search_values)
```

Comment: Thanks, @bringtheheat, but that doesn't work for what I needed. I probably should have had explained myself better when formulating the question, but now it's solved.

Comment: ah, got it. checking out @d.b 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like this?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4) # Data input

a <- unique(a) # Keep unique numbers

a <- sort(a, dec = F) # Sort ascending

tail(a, 3) # Last three numbers in set
```

Gives:

```
[1] 3 4 5
```

In one line:

```
tail(sort(unique(a), dec = F), 3)
```